# How to prevent same page editing collision in Wagtail CMS?

Tags: wagtail

We have a Wagtail site with multiple editors and I want to know how can I prevent same page editing collision in Wagtail CMS?

I know Wagtail has a build in page lock [source](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/v2.4/docs/topics/permissions.rst), but that locks the page for everybody and prevents all edits.

> the ability to lock or unlock this page (and any pages underneath it) for editing, preventing users from making any further edits to it.

I have found https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/448 that seems to be addressing my problem, but it's closed unresolved.

I'm interested to know

1. How can I prevent two or more editors from editing the same page at the same time using Wagtail CMS?

or if 1. is too complex to achieve

2. How can I detect page editing collision and warn editors in Wagtail UI that they may be editing the same page?

Comment: What is the issue with the current lock mechanism? Because if you want to prevent multiple editors to edit the same page, then it's the perfect tool for the job. Is it that it is too restrictive (because it locks all the subpages as well)? Is it that it is a manual operation? Or is it that you still need some editors to be able to edit a locked page?

Comment: Current lock mechanism locks the page for everybody. It's intentioned for moderators (editors don't have permission to use the lock by default) to express "this is the final version of the page, don't touch it". By using page lock I lock everybody including myself out of page editing. I have to unlock the page to be able to edit and if the page is unlocked anyone can edit that page in the same time and that leads to editing collision.

Comment: Oh right. I actually misunderstood the current lock mechanism sorry.

Comment: Note this behaviour changed in Wagtail 2.8:

https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/releases/2.8.html#improved-page-locking

"The page locking feature has been revised so that the editor locking a page is given exclusive edit access to it, rather than it becoming read-only to everyone. A new Reports menu allows admin / moderator level users to see the currently locked pages, and unlock them if required."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to warn before edition or prevent edition completely, I reckon your best option is be the [`before_edit_page` hook](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/reference/hooks.html#before-edit-page) (be careful though, it runs on both the `GET` and `POST` requests) given that it isn't possible to use [custom page permissions](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/2907) at the moment.

This still leaves us with a much bigger question, how to detect that a user is editing a page? There is nothing built-in and unfortunately, I don't think there is an easy solution. Here are some ideas:

**Hooks:** Use the `before_edit_page` and `after_edit_page` hooks to set some sort of flag, let's call it soft-lock. However this fall short rather quickly, what if a user close the page without saving any changes (the `after_edit_page` would never be called and the soft-lock flag would never be removed)? A timeout could be implemented but it could still timeout while someone is editing a page (but just taking a long time) or would still waste someone time as they need to wait for the timeout to happen.

**Ping:** Inject some JavaScript (via the [`insert_editor_js` hook](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/reference/hooks.html#insert-editor-js)) which would pings a custom endpoint with the current user and page id. This could use a much granular frequency than the hook & timeout option.

**Manually** Create some custom soft-lock/soft-unlock actions (via the [`register_page_listing_buttons` and `register_page_listing_more_buttons` hooks](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/reference/hooks.html#register-page-listing-buttons)) to be used manually.

Edit: There's a new interesting package, [Wagtail-Websockets](https://github.com/nypublicradio/wagtail-websockets) which might just solve that issue.

Comment: To build a generic page edit locking mechanism is hard, because it depends on editors intention with the page during the time editor works with it. It may be the reason for Wagtail not having this functionality. Thank you for providing all those options.

Comment: @mojeto, I've added a link to a new open-source package which tries to address page locking as well.